# Play Framework route having "post" word inside URI issues

Tags: scala, rest, playframework, http-headers

I'm having Play endpoint that returns file and which looks like this:

```
  def exportContainerPostCalculations(id: Long): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { implicit request =>
       containerExporter.exportContainerPostCalculationsToCsv(id).map {
          res =>
             Ok.sendFile(new File(res), inline=true).withHeaders(CACHE_CONTROL -> "no-cache", CONTENT_DISPOSITION->s"attachment; filename=${res}", CONTENT_TYPE->"application/x-download");
        }
 }
```

I've intentionally set CACHE_CONTROL to "no-cache" as I want new file to be generated on each service call. I've initially created endpoint that was looking like this:

```
GET          /api/export/container/postcalculations/:id       controllers.ExportController.exportContainerPostCalculations(id: Long)
```

However, this didn't work as expected. It was always returning file from cache and it was using default response headers, so "Cache-control" was always set to "max-age=3600".

It started to work as expected after renaming endpoint to:

```
GET          /api/export/container/finalcalculations/:id       controllers.ExportController.exportContainerPostCalculations(id: Long)
```

I was trying to find in Play documentation anything that would explain why using "post" inside of the route URI would result in such unexpected behavior, but couldn't find anything related. I am wondering if this is just a bug in Play framework or there is something that I missed from documentation.

Comment: I really doubt this is something. More likely you tested a code that was not the one you expected. Did you try having both routes target the same controller method: what happens?

Comment: It really looks weird to me as well, but I also tried what you are suggesting. I also have another identical controller "exportContainerPreCalculations" which works from route .../precalculations/, but not when it's connected to /postcalculations/ route.  I'm pretty sure it's not the case I'm targeting wrong controller.

Comment: I tried to create new project using Play Framework 2.8.2
created similar routes and output to a file with Controller similar to your code
```
GET     /posttest/:id                    controllers.AsyncController.test(id: Long)
```
it works Ok everytime I create the create the request, always returns Cache-Control: no-cache.

Can you give more details about the version you're using?

Comment: It looks like that was the problem somewhere on my side. I'm not able to reproduce the problem anymore neither in sample project nor in original project.